# Zen subtheme, superfish menu etc - invalid CSS

Tags: theming, navigation

I created a sub theme and based it on Zen.

I just validated the CSS locally and there are 66 errors. Any tips on how to use existing modules and themes but reduce the number of css errors?

```
2653    ul li.expanded  Parse Error *list-style-image: url(../images/menu-expanded.png);

2658        Parse Error [: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHAQMAAAD+nMWQAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABJJREFUeJxj+MdQw2DBIMAABgAUsAHD3c3BpwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='); list-style-type: circle; } ul li.collapsed]

2665    ul li.leaf  Parse Error *list-style-image: url(../images/menu-leaf.png);

2674        Parse Error [: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHBAMAAAA2fErgAAAAD1BMVEX///+/v7+Li4sAAADAwMBFvsw8AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAB1JREFUCFtjYAADYwMGBmYVZSDhKAwkFJWhYiAAAB2+Aa/9ugeaAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'); list-style-type: square; } /* * The active item in a Drupal menu */ li a.active]

3012    a.button    Property appearance doesn't exist : button
```

Comment: what type of errors are?

Comment: 2653  ul li.expanded  Parse Error *list-style-image: url(../images/menu-expanded.png);
2658   Parse Error [: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHAQMAAAD+nMWQAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABJJREFUeJxj+MdQw2DBIMAABgAUsAHD3c3BpwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='); list-style-type: circle; } ul li.collapsed]
2665  ul li.leaf  Parse Error *list-style-image: url(../images/menu-leaf.png);


@monymirza

Comment: can u paste css code? and how u validated code?

Comment: @monymirza I am using the Firefox Web Developer Toolbar - Tools - Validate local CSS

Comment: make sure is validate CSS3 as well.

Comment: Thank you @monymirza
Can you recommend a css3 validator?

Comment: check in settings "Web Developer Toolbar"